# IPFS File Upload Vulnerabilities

Tags: security, ipfs

I'm building an app which allows users to upload their images to IPFS and the image will be loaded using an `<img>` tag, the file type checking is done only in the frontend.

However, I'm also aware of the File Upload Vulnerability in normal centralized servers. So here's my question, would hackers be able to explore this?

The following is a JavaScript file I tried to bypass frontend checking and upload to IPFS, however, when I try to access its URL it returns the file in text instead of executing it. As a sophisticated hacker, would he/she be able to upload a malicious file somehow and cause damage on my site or my users?

https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/bafybeigynjetni7b2z52qqv75u5c6k3fgrowqdp6a4qtcbfd4rq7nnj3pu/

Answer (score 0):

All data on ipfs in the public node is Public. If you want to secure files you need to encrypt them. https://docs.ipfs.tech/concepts/privacy-and-encryption/